# Copy skeleton animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I have two bone mesh bodies with the same bone layer, and I want them to use the same animation. However, after associating the animation data, the bones that need to be changed become distorted. I want to know why and how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe the bone orientation is not the same? In that case they won't rotate the same way